# Extends interface of generic type T in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, typescript-typings

Hi am trying to extend interface Message . I am having an error in code as shown below
can someone explain how to proceed with data: T

Am getting the following errors

```
 component.ts:102:8 - error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
    
    102       .subscribe(({ studentId,courseNumber }) => {

 

    node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:51:39
        51     subscribe(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'error' was not provided.
```

In my MessageService.ts i have the following

```
interface Message<T> {
  data :T;
  type: MessageActionType;
}

type Messages = {
  [MessageActionType.TeacherRequest]: Subject<TeacherMessageData>;
  [MessageActionType.StudentRequest]: Subject<StudentMessageData>;
};

type MessageData = TeacherMessageData & PersonProcessWebSocketMessageData ;

private messages: Messages = this.getMessages();

private getMessages(): Messages {
    return Object.values(MessageActionType).reduce(
      (accumulator: Messages, nextValue: MessageActionType) => ({
        ...accumulator,
        [nextValue]: new Subject<object>(),
      }),
      {} as Messages
    );
  }

private messageHandler = ({ data, type }:Message<MessageData>): void => {
    this.messages[type].next(data);
  };


  public save<T extends keyof Messages>(actionType: T): Messages[T] {
    if (!this.messages.hasOwnProperty(actionType)) {
      throw new NonFatalError(
        `cannot save type ${
          actionType as string
        } because it is not a valid ActionType in MessageService`,
        'MessageService.save'
      );
    }

    return this.messages[actionType];
  }
```

In my component i call the service messageservice where i invoke the method save

```
 private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  this.messagesService
      .save(actionType)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(({ studentId, courseNumber }) => {
        if (studentId && courseNumber )
        ) {
          console.log("registered student")
        }
      });
```

In my reference.ts, the data that is needed based on type of action

```
export interface TeacherMessageData{
  teacherId?: number;
  moduleNumber: string;
}

export interface StudentMessageData{
  courseNumber: string;
  studentId?: number;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WG5Y2N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. And remember to aim for a *minimal* example that contains only the code directly necessary to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because TS is using the incorrect (deprecated) overload for `subscribe` which requires at least 2 parameters (as per the error message):

`subscribe(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;`

whereas you want to be using this one in which all parameters are optional:

`subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;`

The only thing I can see which *might* be causing this is that you have an extra  `)` after `if (studentId && courseNumber )` which is might be confusing the compiler - but I am surprised it compiles at all.